# UIImagePickerController image,Display to another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to appear in the "UIImageView" of "PreviewViewController" pictures taken with "ViewController".

But I can not.

Please tell me

ViewController.m

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pic  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];

  UIImage *originalImage;
  originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

CGSize  size = { 100, 200 };
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

CGRect  rect;
rect.origin = CGPointZero;
rect.size = size;
[originalImage drawInRect:rect];
UIImage*    shrinkedImage;
shrinkedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 60, 100, 100);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(shrinkedImage.CGImage, r);
iconImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (iconImage, nil, nil , nil);

// This problem!!!
PreviewViewController *p = [[PreviewViewController alloc] init];
p.imagePreview.image = iconImage;
[self presentViewController:p animated:YES completion:NO];
}
```

PreviewViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imagePreview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a UIImageView that can receive your iconImage?
At first glance I would say that `p.imagePreview == nil` when you are trying to assign an image to it.

If it was created in a .xib, make sure the outlet is connected.

---

From your comment I understand that you are creating your UIImageView in `viewDidLoad`, which is often not call before the view is asked to go to the screen (there are ways to force it to append sooner).
Which means that `p.imagePreview` is probably `nil` when you are assigning your image there.
Have you try to put a `breakpoint` or to `NSLog(@"%@", p.imagePreview);` to see if the instance is valid or not?
If it is `nil` at that point I can think of at least 2 ways of getting around that.

---

You need to revise the UIViewController Life cycle to understand why your p.imagePreview is `nil`.
I suggest that you put `NSLog()` at the start of every method of your `UIViewController` life cycle method. ( All the viewDid..., viewWill..., ) to have a clear picture of the life cycle and understand when thing get call by the system.

As for your problem you could define `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *anImage` and store the image you want to use in your image view there and use that image when initializing your UIImageView in `viewDidLoad`.
Since you are not using a .xib you should also consider overwriting `loadView`.

Comment: I do not use XIB and StoryBoard.Have you created a UIImageView that can receive your iconImage?>What do you mean?

Comment: I want to put in UIimageViewmade(imagePreview) to another class(PreviewViewController).
I made PreviewViewController the imagePreview.

Comment: @onion In your class : PreviewViewController are you doing something like this in `init` : `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame];` ?

Comment: PreviewViewController.h>#import "ViewController.h",{UIImageView *imagePreview;},@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imagePreview;

Comment: PreviewViewController.m>viewDidLoad>imagePreview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 90, 320, 320)];  [self.view addSubview:imagePreview];

Comment: @onion, can you put that into your question so it is readable?

Comment: p.imagePreview.image = iconImage;>NSLog(@"%@",p.imagePreview);>null!!Why?? :-(

Comment: I was able to want to do!! :)

Comment: ,Thank you.Sorry for using your time.